# Buildbot - Two Schedulers with one builder = Double checkin emails?

Tags: buildbot

I have a buildbot running with two Schedulers - One triggered by code checkins and another triggered by content checkins; the former needs a much shorter treeStableTimer.  Both of these Schedulers trigger the same builder, but what happens now is that everyone gets build notification mails twice for each checkin; once for the code scheduler and once for the content scheduler.

For example, if the following checkins go in...
   CL# 1000 12:00pm   user_a   (code)
   CL# 1001 1:00pm    user_b   (content)
...we'd see a build fire off on CL#1000 and send build notification mail to user_a.  Then, a build would fire off from CL#1001 and send build notification to user_a and user_b - user_a gets two notifications that his checkin succeeded, when he should only get one.

I'd like to set things up so that we have two Schedulers, but when a builder triggers and sends email, it sends notification to the number of people who checked in since that builder's last build, not that Scheduler's last build.  This seems straightforward conceptually, but I haven't seen anything on this in the docs or forums.

What's the right way to do this?  We do need different treeStableTimers on the same builder, and people need build mail notification when their build completes, regardless of which of the two Schedulers triggered the builder.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [`fileIsImportant`](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/current/manual/cfg-schedulers.html#singlebranchscheduler) to pick out which which changes to trigger on which scheduler? By default, this doesn't affect the list of changes passed to the source stamp (and build) as triggering the build. All it does is accumulate changes until a change to an important file is made. The [`onlyImportant`](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/current/manual/cfg-schedulers.html#configuring-schedulers) paramaeter of schedulers can be used to discard unimportant changes, so they don't get included in source stamps (and thus don't trigger emails).